# airflow scheduler: WARNING - (parsing_processes = 2) when using sqlite. So we set parallelism to 1

Tags: airflow

[image]

How can I fix the problem here?

I tried to run airflow scheduler but it does not work.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that warning "Because we cannot use more than 1 thread (parsing_processes = 2) when using sqlite. So we set parallelism to 1." is not connected with errors. In my case the problem was caused with the processes using :8793 port. To fix it you could try using these commands:

1. lsof -i :8793 (install lsof beforehand if needed)
2. Kill processes that were printed with the command